# Embedding a youtube video on a Bootstrap website subpage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, embed

I set up a page with a bootstrap template. i generated a number of subpages by copying the index.html

I want a youtube video on one of the subpages. i have tried many code examples however, i only get a result that looks correct, but the video is frozen/locked

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie7 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie8 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en-gb" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <![endif]-->
<title>Los Angeles Teacher</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="WebThemez">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/isotope.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="font/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand scroll-top logo  animated bounceInLeft"><b><i>Los Angeles Teacher</i></b></a> </div>
      <!--/.navbar-header-->
      <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
          <li class="active" id="firstLink"><a href="index.html" class="scroll-link">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="scroll-link">Subjects</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="scroll-link">Qualifications & Lesson Details</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="scroll-link">Rates</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="scroll-link">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
    </nav>
    <!--/.navbar-->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-->
</header>
<!--/.header-->
<div id="#top"></div>
<section id="home">
  <div class="banner-container">

<section id="work" class="page-section page">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="heading">

      <p><br>Learning theory allows new players to <strong>recognize</strong>, <strong>differentiate</strong>, and <strong>prioritize</strong>, <strong>patterns</strong>. First learning theory, a player will process chess theory patterns individually. A player's skill develops as they integrate these pattern processes over time. Learning theory promotes a player's ability to create and critically evaluate strategy.

<br/><br/>Theory promotes understanding of the mechanisms behind wins, losses, and draws. Using theory, players can convert losses in to learning tools.

<br/><br/>Learning theory has applications beyond chess. Anything reliant on pattern recognition, like video games, or music theory, is indirectly improved by learning chess theory. In addition, theory develops a person's intuitive use of a "Deming Cycle".</font><br/><br><img src="demingcycle.png"/><br><br><br><br><h2>Resources</h2>
<img src="chess3.jpg"/><br>
<br>
<img src="chess.gif"/><br>
<br>
<img src="chess.jpg"/><br>
<br>
<img src="brooklyncastle.jpg"/><br>
<br>
<a href="http://www.instantchess.com" target="_blank">
 <img src="instantchess.jpg" />
</a><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="team" class="page-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading text-center">
      <!-- Heading -->

<!--/.page-section-->
<section class="copyright">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center"> Copyright 2015 | All Rights Reserved -- Los Angeles Teacher.com </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / .row -->
  </div>
</section>
<a href="index.html" class="topHome"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-2x"></i></a>

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
<script src="flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code for the page that has the embedded YouTube video? That would help us debug it.

Comment: Aeolingamenfel - here is a code example i tried. the other codes i tried, were slight deviations of this.
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qc_v9mTfhC8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
(this is the code generated off youtube btw, and is also the video i am after). Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: That code by itself works fine. Could you specify the context around that code? The div containing it, or preferrably all the HTML for the page? You can also add that code by using the ` character or `[ctrl]-[k]` when editing your question.

Comment: <!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie7 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie8 oldie no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en-gb" class="isie ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en-gb" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <![endif]-->
<title>Los Angeles Teacher</title>

Comment: <meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="WebThemez">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/isotope.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="font/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

Comment: Aeolingamenfel - i can't copy all the page's html because of space limitations. I have copied a good portion of the beginning. Hopefully this can tell you something that might be inhibiting the video. Thanks!

Comment: JD310 - You can copy the page's html to your answer, by editing the answer. You mostly copied the `<head>` of your document, which probably isn't causing it. The body is more important, and specifically the elements containing the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Aeolingamenfel - thanks for teaching that to me! see any problems with the html layout and the youtube code?

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see the `<iframe>` in that code?

Comment: Aeolingamenfel - the youtube codes were being added behind <img src="brooklyncastle.jpg"/><br>
<br>  (sorry for not noting that, they aren't on the code i just pasted)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a minor syntactical mistake somewhere. It's working great for me:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5bd4ahg/

Video Code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qc_v9mTfhC8">
</iframe>
```

Comment: hi Buck - i still have the original problem. the video is shown but frozen

Comment: Do you have any other constraints besides width and height?

Comment: Hey Buck - So I tried running the code on the original index file and it works perfectly... the problem is, i'm trying to run it on a sub-page i made that was a copy/re-edit of the index file... when i run the code there, it appears perfect, but remains locked/frozen... Any insight?